# Viewpager within a fragment

Tags: xamarin, android-viewpager

I want inside my Fragment I can create a viewpager with 3 fragments, being type carousel. By the activie I can do more for a fragment I can not do, how can I do this?

sorry the English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If I understand you correctly,You want a activity which have more
  than one fragments ,yes it possible, there are many examples on
  internet
- In addition, you wanna create  a view pager,and  it occur
  fragments,Yes it is possible you can create FragmentPagerAdapter
  then,set view pager.adapter your's adapter,this adapter returns
  fragments according to view pager position

Comment: Example of how I want it, you can see that it has a viewpager inside a fragment:    -- >  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xl81-DbEC5o

Comment: tutorial for how  ->
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/viewpager/part-2-viewpager-and-fragments/
Example->
https://gist.github.com/AlejandroRuiz/c1338bb0166754c6da3d